# Trying to use JavascriptExecutor to test a button but getting 'Unexpected keyword or identitfier'

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, testing

I have the following line in my code:

`JavascriptExector js = (JavascriptExector) driver;`

I'm getting red lines under it with the error message `Unexpected keyword or identifier`

i tried importing `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;` but I got this error:

```
import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8002)
```

I'm new to JavaScript I mostly use python, thanks!

Comment: You're doing that in Java? You should show more code.

Answer (score 0):

It is `JavascriptExecutor`, not `JavascriptExector`.

Comment: answering questions [that should be closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/11107541) is discouraged. see [answer].